# Upgrade PHP PDO_PGSQL version from 8.4 to 9.4 EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdo, amazon-ec2, php-pgsql

I have an EC2 Amazon Linux Ami instance running PHP server version 5.6.22, also PostgreSQL 9.4.6 installed.

Doing an echo phpinfo(); it give the following value for PDO_PGSQL library:

PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   8.4.20

This is causing that the app server throws error while trying to connect to the RDS instance with Postgres 9.5 due to the missmatching versions.

I have been looking to make that version to be 9.4 or 9.5. Until now, I had done severals reinstall, trying dealing with repositories, but without results.

EDIT:
The reported version for psql command is: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.6

Comment: Take a look here: http://tecadmin.net/install-postgresql-9-5-on-centos/#

Comment: @PhillipBerger I've tried that, but the issue seems to be with some past version installed of postgres in EC2 Amazon Linux AMI instance, and PHP PDO library seems to be always taking the postgres 8.4.20 library version. .

Answer (score 0):

Its very old but I wanted to write.
I had the same issue and thought that error caused by php libpq exactly like you.
I tried million times to reinstall everything, changed OS but no result. Then I found some other setting that can cause the error. That was "Security Groups". You can find it under EC2 page menu. Please switch inbound source "everywhere" for "rds-launch-wizard" group then try to connect again.

It should work, if other every options are O.K.

Good luck.